# About "The product of the six numbers surrounding any interior number in Pascal’s triangle is a perfect square"

Tags: binomial-coefficients, products

The current Futility Closet
has this statement:
"The product of the six numbers surrounding any interior number in Pascal’s triangle is a perfect square."

Here is the link with a nice illustration:
http://www.futilitycloset.com/2016/07/14/a-square-triangle/

Here is the proof I found:

At $c(n, m)$,
the neighbors are
$(n-1, m-1), (n-1, m),
(n, m-1), (n, m+1),
(n+1, m), (n+1, m+1)
$.

The product is

$\begin{array}\\
p(n, m)
&=c(n-1, m-1)c(n-1, m)
c(n, m-1)c(n, m+1)
c(n+1, m)c(n+1, m+1)\\
&=\frac{(n-1)!^2n!^2(n+1)!^2}{(m-1)!(n-m)!m!(n-1-m)!(m-1)!(n-m+1)!(m+1)!(n-m-1)!m!(n-m+1)!(m+1)!(n-m)!}\\
&=\frac{(n-1)!^2n!^2(n+1)!^2}{(m-1)!^2(n-m)!^2m!^2(n-1-m)!^2(n-m+1)!^2(m+1)!^2}\\
&=\left(\frac{(n-1)!n!(n+1)!}{(m-1)!m!(m+1)!(n-1-m)!(n-m)!(n-m+1)!}\right)^2\\
\end{array}
$

I have two questions:

(1) Since the result is so nice,
it seems to me that
there should be a
simpler,
more intuitive proof.
Is there?

(2) These are the product
of the binomial coefficients
adjacent to $(n, m)$,
or at distance 1.
What about the coefficients
and distance 2, or,
more generally, k.
How would we state the
product of such coefficients
and what properties
would it have
(e.g.,
would it be a k-th power)?

Comment: For (2), the first instance of distance-2-products is centred on $\binom{4}{2}=6$, and the product of all numbers within distance $2$ is $2^9\cdot 3^4\cdot5^7$, which is not an interesting power. The product of all numbers with distance _exactly_ $2$ is $2^3\cdot 5^5$, and it's still not anything noteworthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad. (2): A generalisation of this property can be found in *[Generalized hidden hexagon squares](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/12-1/gupta.pdf)* by A.K.Gupta.

> For positive integers $r_1,r_2$ the following product spaced around $\binom{n}{m}$ is a perfect square
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{n-r_1}{m-r_2}\binom{n-r_1}{m}\binom{n}{m-r_2}
> \binom{n+r_2}{m+r_1}\binom{n+r_2}{m}\binom{m}{m+r_2}
> \end{align*}
>   If $r_1=r_2$ the product is *equally spaced* around $\binom{n}{m}$, if $r_1=r_2=1$ we get the point of origin.

Answer (score 0):

For (1), noticing that
$$\binom{n-1}{m-1}\binom{n}{m+1}\binom{n+1}{m}=\binom{n-1}{m}\binom{n+1}{m+1}\binom{n}{m-1}\tag3$$
holds should make it simpler to prove the claim.

Writing $\binom ab$ as $\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$, one sees that the numerators on both sides of $(3)$ are $(n-1)!n!(n+1)!$, and that the denominators on both sides are the product of $(m-1)!m!(m+1)!$ and $(n-m-1)!(n-m)!(n-m+1)!$.

Comment: This is basically the same thing, i.e. writing out all the binomial coefficients in terms of factorials and see that they all pair up.